# PostGis geometry name lookup failed for table

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, mapnik, osm2pgsql

I have a table name erpAssets which has column name Region of type polygon. it contains entries of points also like (-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837)).

I have written query which convert these points to geometry which is used by mapnick to generate tiles.

(
SELECT replace(concat(concat('POINT',concat(trim(TRAILING ')'FROM  concat('(',trim(LEADING '(' FROM region::TEXT)::TEXT) ),')')),''),',',' ') as data
 from "erpAssets" where parent=326815) as foo
        ) as points

My osm.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Map [
<!ENTITY % entities SYSTEM "inc/entities.xml.inc">
%entities;
]>
<Map background-color="#bb0000" srs="&srs900913;" minimum-version="2.0.0">
  &fontset-settings;
 <Style name="theme_park">
     <Rule>
      <PointSymbolizer file="&symbols;/alpinehut.p.16.png" 

      />

    </Rule>

</Style>

&layer-shapefiles;
<Layer name="theme_park" status="on" srs="&osm2pgsql_projection;">
    <StyleName>theme_park</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
      <Parameter name="table">
        (SELECT ST_GeomFromText(data)
FROM
(
SELECT replace(concat(concat('POINT',concat(trim(TRAILING ')'FROM  concat('(',trim(LEADING '(' FROM region::TEXT)::TEXT) ),')')),''),',',' ') as data
 from "erpAssets" where parent=326815) as foo       
        ) as points

      </Parameter>
      &datasource-settings;
    </Datasource>
</Layer>
</Map>
```

Tiles are not generated and i am getting error on console as follows:
Postgis Plugin: geometry name lookup failed for table '"erpassets"'. Please manually provide the 'geometry_field' parameter or add an entry in the geometry_columns for '"erpassets"'.

I have converted region column into geometry by aliasing then why i am not getting points on map?

Comment: A column of type polygon that contains points? I do not understand from what you are trying to build geometries. But to build a PostGIS geometry you will need to use a geometry constructor function like ST_Point(x, y).

Comment: What's in `&osm2pgsql_projection;`? If 900013, that's an error: you need to specify the data is in WGS-84.

Comment: @IljaZverev i am newbie to this can u tell me where to check this and change it to WGS-84?

Comment: @NicklasAvén check my select query which make required geomtery from regions of my points

Comment: @IljaZverev thanks i have changed that in my settings.xml file now tiles are generated but i cant see points of my image ?

Comment: You have `srs="&srs900913;"` for the Map and `srs="&osm2pgsql_projection;"` for the layer. This might go wrong if both are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

How applications use PostGIS is they look up the metadata for geometry columns in the `geometry_columns` view (formerly a table). How you have set up the query is that each time `regions`, a text column, is translated and converted to a `geometry` column. However, since this result is part of a query, and not part of a table, it does not appear in `geometry_columns`, as Mapnik expects.

Add a geometry column and update your source table:

```
ALTER TABLE "erpAssets" ADD COLUMN geom(POINT,4326);

UPDATE "erpAssets" SET
  geom = ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT' ||
              replace(substr(region, 2, length(region) - 2), ',', ' '));
```

Then update your Mapnik query to something simpler, like:

```
SELECT geom
FROM "erpAssets"
WHERE parent=326815;
```

(Note: use the SRID that applies to your question. I'm only guessing `4326`)

Comment: thanks for replying me back. sir i have long,lat data but maonik is using srs900913 for projection. and it is only drawing one point. when i change projection to srs4326 then it is giving error